# How to scale Google App Engine instances down to 0 when there is no traffic?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am hosting an app on GAE and want to enable auto-scaling down to 0 instances when there is no traffic. I thought that specifying `min_instances: 0` would allow that to happen. I also included the `warmup` process recommended in the docs.

I sent a single request to the app in the morning and didn't touch it again but it still racked up 10+ instance hours.

Can anyone tell me how to enable scale-down to 0 instance on the standard environment?

I'll also note that I''m using a few other GCP services, including pubsub and secretmanager. Do those accumulate F-class instance hours?

```
service: default
runtime: python37

instance_class: F4_1G

automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.80
  min_instances: 0    # should enables aut-scaling down to 0 instances when no traffic
  max_instances: 2
  max_pending_latency: 2000ms
  min_pending_latency: 30ms    # default

entrypoint: python -m api.app

handlers:
  - url: /home
    script: auto


inbound_services:
  - warmup    # sends GET request to application's /_ah/warmup endpoint
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you also added an `/_ah/warmup` route to your app as well, correct?

Comment: I did, yes. It just returns a 200 OK

Comment: the instance is idle or active? Also are you sure the app terminates correctly and it does not keep doing some extra work on the background?

Comment: Idle, I suppose. There's no traffic hitting the app and no traffic leaving. The `availability` of the instance is "dynamic". I hadn't thought to verify all background tasks. Hmm, I'll check that next. Thanks.

Comment: There was indeed a sub-process that was not always killed properly. Seems like the YML above is viable for auto-scale down to 0 instance. Thanks!

Comment: I'll post an answer with your findings and my suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed)

> App Engine can automatically create and shut down instances as traffic
>   fluctuates, or you can specify a number of instances to run regardless
>   of the amount of traffic.

This means that if an instance does not work in a log time, it will be shut down or in the case that you have configured [min_idle_instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#scaling_elements) this instances will kept running and ready to serve traffic.

On the App Engine Dashboard, select the instances menu, then on the Summary drop-down select Instances, there you will be able to see if your instance is active.

If there are active instances this will probably mean your instance is still doing some work, a background task or maybe there is something stuck.

if there are idle instances this will be thanks to your [app.yaml config file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref), where you setup the minimum idle instances and there are not working but ready to serve, however you will be billed for this instances too.