# GAE: why the instance didn't get killed when there's no traffic for 2 days

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

it's a python 3.7 standard env with:

```
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
```

- `2020-07-21 10:06:30` last request received
- [nothing happened according to the log]
- `2020-07-23 15:10:23` I manually disabled the GAE service, the log shows instance getting killed

The expected behavior would be instance get killed sometime after the last request, but nothing happened in two days.

My question is very simply: why the instance didn't get killed when there's no traffic for 2 days?

GAE dashboard shows the instance 'created' but not 'active'

here's the log:

[image]

Comment: What's you question? Your concern? Are you billed on these instances?

Comment: Your Concern or Question is not clear enough. Are you wondering why your App Engine Standard application is not scaling down to 0 Instances? As you may already know, [App Engine standard applications scales down to 0 when there is no traffic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#the_app_engine_environments).

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere,  my question is the instance supposed to get killed if there's no traffic for two days. I don't think I get billed according to the dashboard.  but this behavior is strange to me

Comment: This is serverless. You don't manage the server/instance lifecycle. Google is in charge of this.

Answer (score 0):

As you may already know, [App Engine standard applications scales down to 0 when there is no traffic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#the_app_engine_environments). The App Engine autoscaler scales down App Engine instances to ensure optimal use and cost effectiveness by turning off its associated dynamic instances when there are no traffic to the Instance.

[As explained here](https://serverfault.com/questions/985231/gae-automatic-scaling-does-not-scale-down-to-0#answer-985268) by one of GCP Support Engineers, for automatic_scaling, if you declare min_idle_instances: 0, all your instances are dynamic instances and these instances will be started and shut down depending on the needs for the instances (e.g. more or less traffic).

Please note that it may take a while for the Cloud console to refresh its information and reflect no instances running for applications no serving traffic. More importantly if you are not incurring billing charges for running instances, it may simply be that the Console is not updating its information yet.

With all that being said, we acknowledge that there are [situ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61001834/how-to-scale-google-app-engine-instances-down-to-0-when-there-is-no-traffic)[ations](https://issuetracker.google.com/74352250) when the Instances have been reported not to have scaled down as expected. Some of these were a result of background tasks and sub-processes still running. If you want to be extra-sure about the serving instances, I recommend [you reach out to the GCP support engineers](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/support-hub), who would check your project to confirm whether or not, there are running background processes.